# SIT in rails not working for audited-activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am not able to retrieve `auditable_type` for the child table record associated audits as it always gives parent table class name.

**I have:**

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :diseases
 has_associated_audits
end

class Disease < MedicalHistory
 belongs_to :patient
 audited associated_with :patient
end

class MedicalHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

when I make `Patient.last.associated_audits.last.auditable_type`  give MedicalHistory instead of Disease.

**Please let me know ASAP.**

Comment: It would be good if you remove ASAP. Our Stack will always help you on time

Comment: If you visit the gem's site, you will not find mention of single table inheritance functionality. What you claim is "not working" I would posit is a feature which the maintainers/caretakers do not advertise. It is open source software, you should consider forking a repository and crafting it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it has been an issue in this gem.

But you can retrieve the audited record first and then identify its class name like :

```
Patient.last.associated_audits.last.auditable.class.name
```

Actually, in Single table inheritance (STI) each record will have a unique id so you can identify the record using the record id from the parent class as `MedicalHistory.find(child_id)`